# Candy machine Sugar Minting button disabled on deploy

Tags: solana-program, web3.js, sugar, candymachine

I deployed a candy machine. But it minting button is disabled and its not showing any error  or message on screen that why its disabled. I have all NFTs available to mint and sale is live.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have balance in your wallet. That might be the issue.